# How to display edited node/edge property as label in cytoscape js?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Using cytoscape.js I can display the `name` property of my data as a label like this:

```
'label': 'data(name)'
```

Is there a possibility to display an edited version without changing the `name` in the data? For example a substring like this:

```
'label': 'data({name.split('.')[0]})'
```

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "data(name)" is equal to javascript code:

```
data["name"]
```

or just

```
data.name
```

Thus, your node data must have proper key/value, for example:

```
{ data: { id: "j", name: "Jerry"}}
```

So that, the node's `data.name` can return something ("Jerry" in this case). Valid code is limited to the node's data extraction. General javascript code is not possible due to security reasons.

In conclusion, there is no possibility to use:

```
'label': 'data({name.split('.')[0]})'
```

because there will be an error due to invalid code.